How Can I Connect to a Kubernetes RabbitMQ Cluster Using a Pika Connection in Python?
I am trying to establish a connection to my RabbitMQ Cluster running in a Kubernetes Service using a Pika connection in Python.
I've successfully created my RabbitMQ cluster by running kubectl apply -f definition.yaml in Azure CLI.
Here is my definition.yaml file. I am trying to keep it very basic to start off.
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
  name: test-cluster-successful
  namespace: successful-cluster
spec:
  replicas: 3
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-cluster-service
  namespace: successful-cluster
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-cluster-successful
  ports:
    - name: amqp
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
    - name: management
      port: 15672
      targetPort: 15672
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer

In the above yaml I'm creating a RabbitMQ Cluster, then using the LoadBalancer to expose an external IP in order to be able to connect to it from my code. I'm able to run rabbitmqctl cluster_status in a pod and see all 3 nodes are listed as running in a cluster.
Here is my Python code I'm using to try to connect to the cluster with.
username = '<TEST_USER>'
password = '<TEST_PASSWORD>'
usercredentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username, password)

parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('<EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS>', 5672, '/', usercredentials)
self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
self.channel = self.connection.channel()

I originally was simply using pika.ConnectionParameters('<EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS>', 5672) but getting an error that ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN so I created my own user and password and passing it in through my Python code but getting the same error. I verified the username and password are correct but it's not being treated any differently.
NOTE: I've included the full error at the bottom since it's pretty long.
I can tell it's hitting a valid IP address since it otherwise gives a timed out error when I pass in a random IP address. Also, when I run ping <EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS> it gets replies properly.
I am also having an issue that I am not able to access the RabbitMQ management dashboard at http://<EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS>:15672 even though I added a 15672 port in my yaml file but my main goal is to establish a Pika connection to the 5672 port.
I know I wrote quite a bit but I figure it's better to include too much detail than not enough. If you have any questions feel free to ask and I will clarify where I can and if you've read this far I appreciate your time.
The full error from PyTest in my local command prompt:
ERROR    pika.connection:connection.py:2054 Connection closed while authenticating indicating a probable authentication error
ERROR    pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:connection_workflow.py:291 AMQPConnector - reporting failure: AMQPConnectorAMQPHandshakeError: ProbableAuthenticationError: Client was disconnected at a connection stage indicating a probable authentication error: ("ConnectionClosedByBroker: (403) 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.'",)
ERROR    pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:connection_workflow.py:746 AMQP connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorAMQPHandshakeError: ProbableAuthenticationError: Client was disconnected at a connection stage indicating a probable authentication error: ("ConnectionClosedByBroker: (403) 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.'",); first exception - None.
ERROR    pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:connection_workflow.py:723 AMQPConnectionWorkflow - reporting failure: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorAMQPHandshakeError: ProbableAuthenticationError: Client was disconnected at a connection stage indicating a probable authentication error: ("ConnectionClosedByBroker: (403) 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.'",); first exception - None
ERROR    pika.adapters.blocking_connection:blocking_connection.py:450 Connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorAMQPHandshakeError: ProbableAuthenticationError: Client was disconnected at a connection stage indicating a probable authentication error: ("ConnectionClosedByBroker: (403) 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.'",); first exception - None
ERROR    pika.adapters.blocking_connection:blocking_connection.py:457 Error in _create_connection().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER_NAME\repos\web-dashboard-backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError: ConnectionClosedByBroker: (403) 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.'
ERROR    pyignite.connection:connection.py:131 Failed to perform handshake, connection to node(address=127.0.0.1, port=10800) with protocol context ProtocolContext(version=(1, 7, 0), features=4) failed: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER_NAME\repos\web-dashboard-backend\dashboard\notification\message_broker.py", line 96, in create_connection
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER_NAME\repos\web-dashboard-backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER_NAME\repos\web-dashboard-backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError: ConnectionClosedByBroker: (403) 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER_NAME\repos\web-dashboard-backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyignite\connection\connection.py", line 241, in connect
    result = self._connect_version()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER_NAME\repos\web-dashboard-backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyignite\connection\connection.py", line 271, in _connect_version
    self._socket.connect((self.host, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
ERROR    root:kafka_fallback_handler.py:45 KafkaFallbackHandler: Create connection exception: Can not connect.
ERROR    dashboard.notification.message_broker:message_broker.py:132 Exception while creating connection with rabbitMq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER_NAME\repos\web-dashboard-backend\dashboard\notification\message_broker.py", line 96, in create_connection
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER_NAME\repos\web-dashboard-backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER_NAME\repos\web-dashboard-backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError: ConnectionClosedByBroker: (403) 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.'


More info about your kube environment please :)
Is this a local cluster? If cloud which?

Sure thing, my kube environment is a Kubernetes Service running in Azure
